# qreal being treated as Qreal&

Tags: c++, qt

I facing some strange problem in my qt code

```
            qreal x1 = firstPoint.x();
            qreal y1 = firstPoint.y();
            qreal x2 = wid;
            qreal y2 = ht;

            OverlayLine* temp = qobject_cast<OverlayLine *>(overlayFact->createObject("Line",this));
            temp->setDimensions(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            temp->isMovable = true;
            temp->isUserRemovable = true;
            temp->isResizable = true;
```

Prototype of function setDimensions is as follows

```
virtual void setDimensions(qreal x, qreal y, qreal w, qreal h);
```

But while compiling i am getting this error

error: no matching function for call to 'OverlayLine::setDimensions(qreal&, qreal&, qreal&, qreal&)'
             temp->setDimensions(x1, y1, x2, y2);
                                               ^

am i missing something?
Also strangely, if i modify my code to

```
            qreal x2 = wid;
            qreal y2 = ht;

            OverlayLine* temp = qobject_cast<OverlayLine *>(overlayFact->createObject("Line",this));
            temp->setDimensions(firstPoint.x(), firstPoint.y(), x2, y2);
            temp->isMovable = true;
            temp->isUserRemovable = true;
            temp->isResizable = true;
```

i get following error

error: no matching function for call to 'OverlayLine::setDimensions(qreal, qreal, qreal&, qreal&)'
             temp->setDimensions(firstPoint.x(), firstPoint.y(), x2, y2);
                                                                       ^

Comment: Make sure you don't have a typo (and/or hidden rather than overriden methods somewhere). Those added references in the error message for l-values are normal.